# Sequentially arranged and add placeholders in text file

Tags: c#, file

I have a text file which contains data. There are 3 columns, each column starts at a specific location and ends a specific location in the file. The first column which is (300, 301, 302, 304...) is always number based. the second column is a string, and the last column is currency.

The current .txt file is missing numbers which is (303, 305).
I was able to find the missing numbers and add it to an array then write it to the file.

My goal is to write all the columns data sequentially to the text file even the missing ones. As for column 2 and 3, I want `0` to be the placeholder for the missing data and aligned with its own column.

I'm close but need help

```
   //read file
   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
   var Numbers = new List<int>();
   int i = 0;
   foreach (var line in lines)
   {
       //get value of first column
       var FirstColumn = line.Substring(0, 3);
       //add it to array
       Numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(FirstColumn));
       ++i;
   }
   //find missing numbers add to array
   var result = Enumerable.Range(Numbers.Min(), Numbers.Count);            

   //write to file
   using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(OutPutFile, true))
   {
       foreach (var item in result.ToArray())
       {
           file.WriteLine(item);
       }                
   }


   Console.ReadKey();
```

**Current .txt file**

```
300     Family Guy      1,123
301     Dexters Lab     456
302     Rugrats         1,789.52
304     Scooby-Doo      321
306     Recess          2,654
307     Popeye          1,987.02
```

**GOAL: Desired Output .txt file**

```
300     Family Guy      1,123
301     Dexters Lab     456
302     Rugrats         1,789.52
303     0               0
304     Scooby-Doo      321
305     0               0
306     Recess          2,654
307     Popeye          1,987.02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the first column, but not the rest.  What I do is create a dictionary, using the first number as the index, and stuffing the other two fields into a `System.ValueTuple` (you need to include the ValueTyple Nuget package to get this to work).

First I set some stuff up:

```
 const int column1Start = 0;
 const int column1Length = 3;
 const int column2Start = 8;
 const int column2Length = 15;
 const int column3Start = 24;

 int indexMin = int.MaxValue;     //calculated during the first
 int indexMax = int.MinValue;     //pass through the file
```

Then I create my dictionary.  That `(string, decimal)` syntax describes a 2-tuple that contains a string and a decimal number (kind of like the ordered-pairs you were taught about in high school).

```
 Dictionary<int, (string, decimal)> data = new Dictionary<int, (string, decimal)>();
```

Then I make a pass through the file's lines, reading through the data, and stuffing the results in my dictionary (and calculating the max and min values for that first column):

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
 foreach (var line in lines) {
     //no error checking
     var indexString = line.Substring(column1Start, column1Length);
     var cartoon = line.Substring(column2Start, column2Length).TrimEnd();
     var numberString = line.Substring(column3Start);

     if (int.TryParse(indexString, out var index)) {
         //I have to parse the first number - otherwise there's nothing to index on
         if (!decimal.TryParse(numberString, out var number)){
             number = 0.0M;
         }
         data.Add(index, (cartoon, number));

         if (index < indexMin) {
             indexMin = index;
         }
         if (index > indexMax) {
             indexMax = index;
         }
     }
 }
```

Finally, with all my data in hand, I iterate from the min value to the max value, fetching the other two columns out of my dictionary:

```
 for (int i = indexMin; i <= indexMax; ++i) {
     if (!data.TryGetValue(i, out var val)){
         val = ("0", 0.0M);
     }
     Console.WriteLine($"{i,5}  {val.Item1,-column2Length - 2}  {val.Item2, 10:N}");
 }
```

My formatting isn't quite the same as yours (I cleaned it up a bit).  You can do what you want.  My results look like:

```
  300  Family Guy           1,123.00
  301  Dexters Lab            456.00
  302  Rugrats              1,789.52
  303  0                        0.00
  304  Scooby-Doo             321.00
  305  0                        0.00
  306  Recess               2,654.00
  307  Popeye               1,987.02
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran your code and reviewed it. It works!!